# Get network.request response headers in lua

Tags: networking, lua, http-headers, httpresponse, coronasdk

I’m using network.request like this:

```
network.request( fullUrl, "POST", networkListener, params)
```

and receiving the response in my network listener as such:

```
local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        response = {};
    else
        response = json.decode(event.response);
    end
end
```

I am receiving the body response of the request but **I want to receive the request’s response headers as well. How can I achieve this?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for `network.request`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html) says:

> ```
> network.request( url, method, listener [, params] )
> ```
>
> listener (required)
>
> [Listener](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Listener.html). The listener function invoked at various phases of the HTTP operation. This is passed a [networkRequest](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/networkRequest/index.html) event.

And [the documentation for `networkRequest`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/networkRequest/index.html) links to [event.responseHeaders](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/networkRequest/responseHeaders.html), which gives this example:

```lua
-- Print the Content-Type header value for a response
local function networkListener( event )
    print( "Content-Type of response is: " .. event.responseHeaders["Content-Type"] )
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I don't know how I didn't found the documentation for that which is so obvious